# Diodon visible on "ALT+TAB"?

Tags: application-switcher, clipboard-manager

Since some days the handy clipboard manager Diodon is always visible
if I use Alt+TAB.

[image: diodon-always-visible]

This was not the case in the past.

I would like to not see the preview, when I switch between windows.

How to hide Diodon again?

I use Ubuntu 20.04.