# CopyQ Window visible on ALT+TAB

Tags: application-switcher, clipboard-manager

Since some days [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) is visible if I use ALT+TAB:

[image: copy-visible]

This was different in the past.

I think it does not make sense to show this window. You usually use a shortcut to open
the clipboard manager.

How to hide this window again?

I use the default Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome Environment

Comment: Mention your desktop environment.

Comment: With reading of your previous [question about Diodon](https://askubuntu.com/q/1306636/66509) I can recommend to drop GNOME Shell and install MATE DE instead. In MATE both applications are presented only in tray/notification-area.

Comment: @vanadium I use the default Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome Environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "File - Preferences" of the CopyQ application, enable "Hide main window" on the "Layout" tab. This will cause CopyQ to be removed from the Alt+Tab pop up whenever the window is closed.

Comment: Thank you very much!